# Can't reach Apache on Docker from Windows Server 2016 host machine

Tags: apache, docker, nano-server

Heads up: I'm a novice in both general web administration and Docker. My errors *could* be caused by something very stupid.

I am running Docker for Windows Server 2016 (the native variant). I have pulled and built a simple Docker base image with Nano Server and Apache 2.4 (nanoserver/apache24). I have made a container from this image and mapped the container port 80 to my local port 8082.

From inside the container, I can use `Invoke-WebRequest -uri http://localhost:80` and retrieve the default apache document. However, I would also expect `Invoke-WebRequest -uri http://localhost:8082` from *outside* the container to retrieve the same file. This does not work. I have also tried using the container NAT address, running `Invoke-WebRequest -uri http://172.23.58.7:8082`. This does not work neither. What is it that I have misconfigured here?

Screenshot from my process below. PowerShell in host computer on the left, PowerShell inside container on the right.

[image: Screenshot of my errors]

EDIT: @Grimmy asked me in the comment section whether I do have `EXPOSE 80` in my Dockerfile and whether `docker ps` command displays my container with the expected port mapping. It's yes on both counts. My container runs with arguments `-d -it` because it was a quick Google fix to the problem where the container exits immediately after launch. I know `-i` "keeps STDIN open" and `-t` "allocates pseudo-tty", but I frankly don't understand what either of those imply or whether it could be relevant to the problem.

EDIT2: I did not explicitly mention this in the original post, but it's worth noting that `netstat -a -o` does *not* display a PID listening on port 8082. I would expect this to be the case.  Should it be the case?

The first 50 lines or so of output is displayed in the screenshot.

Comment: Have you tried running `docker ps` and making sure that the container is running? If it is, connect to the shell with `docker exec -it container_id some_command`

Comment: Yes. The window on the right hand side in my screenshot is from powershell.exe inside the container.  From there, I can retrieve the apache webpage with no problem.

Comment: Your `Dockerfile` also have `EXPOSE 80` in it?

Comment: Also run `docker ps` and make sure the `PORTS` column actually displays the port mappings. It should display something like `0.0.0.0:8082->80/tcp`

Comment: It's also a very common mistake forgetting to rebuild a new image when making changes. Overall what you describe here looks perfectly sane.

Comment: Just noticed you are using `-dit`. Not sure what that will imply for the running container. `run -d` should be enough.

Comment: @Grimmy, yes I do have EXPOSE 80, and the `docker ps` command does display the correct port mapping. I don't quite understand what the `-i` and `-t` parameters do; they were a quick fix that I googled in order to not have the container quit immediately after it was run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from 'artisticcheese' [in the Docker Forums.](https://forums.docker.com/t/my-windows-server-2016-host-os-does-not-listen-to-the-port-that-my-container-is-mapped-to/35286/4)

> You can not connect to mapped IP address within container host itself.
>   it’s bug in Windows implementation of WinNAT. You need get private IP
>   address of container and connect to it using port number. Or you can
>   access through public mapped port from another host on the same
>   network, that shall work.

I connected from another host, and it worked immediately. I frankly don't know what the "private IP address" of the container is as opposed to the NAT address, so I couldn't proceed on the other tip.